# AWS Cognito user's sub changes on getAuthenticationDetails

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

When my client application calls `getAuthenticationDetails` on `AuthenticationHandler` (Java), the user's `sub` saved on Cognito changes. In many reviews relating AWS sub's usage, they use the sub as their uuid in their databases. Why is my sub value changing and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can I get the steps for reproducing this? Do you mean the sub in the idToken or accessToken? The sub should be as you said, unique to a user and unless the user (with the same username) is deleted and created again, the sub value shouldn't change.